# How to get UIButton position in an auto layout View

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

I have a `UIButton` on `UIView's` controller. The position of `UIButton` is 10pixel from top of UIView and 10 pixel from another UILabel which is 20 pixel from UIView's trailing position. Both `UIButton` & `UILabel` have same height and width. The view is designed in auto layout mode.

The position of button & label in `UIView's` controller

```
UIView

  -> `UIButton`, `UILabel`

------------------------------
|                 |          |
|                10          |
|                 |          |
|                B - 20 - L  |
|                            |
------------------------------
```

The position of UIButton retrieved in `ViewDidLoad` method is not correct as it reflects initial position from xib but after view is loaded the button position will be changed as auto layout is being used.

Let me know how can i retrieve `UIButton` position(x & y) once the `UIView` is displayed.

The `viewdidload` method is as below,

```
- (void) Viewdidload() {

     [UIView addSubview:object1];
     ---
     [UIView addSubview:object2];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is a good place where you can get the correct the correct coordinates of your button, even after rotation or any subsequent changes in view's layout.

Comment: @AdilSoomro, viewDidLayoutSubviews() will be called for every subview added or removed. In my case couple of times this method is being called and i could observe different value of UIButton position.

Comment: Ideally you'll not add new views in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` rather you'll simply set their frame or coordinates if required.

Comment: Please note that ViewWIllAppera is the best place to get autolayout. viewDidLayoutSubviews also gets called with ViewWillAppear but not every time. On Device rotation only viewDidLayoutSubviews() gets call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The views are not (auto)layout-ed at the time in the life cycle `viewDidLoad()` is called.

Get the position in `viewDidAppear()` or `viewWillAppear()`.

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews() is probably the better option

Comment: @picciano Why is it better?

Comment: It may work most of the time, but viewDidAppear is only called once, perhaps before additional layout is performed in subsequent calls to layoutSubviews. It also will not get called again if the layout is performed again, such as an orientation change, or the addition of other subviews.

Comment: @picciano how I understand the question the OP wants to "retrieve UIButton position(x & y) once the UIView is displayed". For which `viewDid/WillAppear()` is the correct method in my understanding.